# Looping though Series collection in MS Chart

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a chart which I would like to change the color of its columns if the label value on the SeriesCollections DataLabels is greater than the Value
on its sister DataLabel
For example if `SeriesCollection(1)` with `DataLabel(1) > DataLabel(2)` Then `.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Interior.Color = RGB(250, 0, 0)`

I have this code which misses out some SerieCollections and also changes the color of the columns regardless of the DataLabel.Caption Value

```
Dim labelCaption As Currency
Dim k As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim c As Object
Set c = myChart.Object

With c
 For k = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
   For j = 1 To .SeriesCollection(k).Points.Count
   labelCaption = .SeriesCollection(k).Points(j).DataLabel.Text
   If labelCaption > .SeriesCollection(k).Points(j).DataLabel.Text Then
   .SeriesCollection(k).Points(j).Interior.Color = RGB(250, 0, 0)
   Else
   .SeriesCollection(k).Points(j).Interior.Color = 65280
   End If
   Next j
    
 Next k
End With
```

**Edit**
The RowSource of `myChart` is:

`Me.myChart.RowSource = "SELECT [AreaDonor],[NetDonation],[DonationLimit] FROM [qryDonationComparison];"`

In other words if the value of `NetDonation` is greater than the value of `DonationLimit` then change the color of colunm corresponding to that `DataLabel` with `NetDonation` to red else leave it green.

This is the sample data.

[image]

This is the Chart I am getting:

[image]

Comment: I experimented with something like this once and used Text instead of Caption property.

Comment: @June7 Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Elaborate how? Where you use `.Caption`, I used `.Text`. My procedure did work. However, your nested looping doesn't make sense to me. Edit question to show sample data and an image of chart.

Comment: @June7 I have changed the `.Caption` to `.Text` The problem seems to be coming from the `If` statement. Did you previously use a if statement to compare the `.Tex` property of the DataLabels?

Comment: Didn't compare two labels but compared label to an input. Edit question as suggested and I might be able to help. Also, show chart RowSource SQL.

Comment: @June7 Question edited. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Also asked for sample data and image of chart. What type of chart are you building?

Comment: Oh I don't know how to add images but its a column chart.

Comment: @June7 image added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
With c
For j = 1 To .SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
    If CDbl(.SeriesCollection(1).Points(j).DataLabel.Text) > CDbl(.SeriesCollection(2).Points(j).DataLabel.Text) Then
        .SeriesCollection(1).Points(j).Interior.Color = RGB(250, 0, 0)
    Else
        .SeriesCollection(1).Points(j).Interior.Color = 65280
    End If
Next j
End With
```

Comment: You rock. For some reason my `Points` were not changing color so I had to convert the `.Text` to `Double` Then it worked. Perhaps I was doing something wrong? If you agree please edit the code a bit so I can mark it as complete. I used: `Dim Label1 As Double
Dim Label2 As Double
Dim c As Object
Dim j As Integer
With c
For j = 1 To .SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
Label1 = .SeriesCollection(1).Points(j).DataLabel.Text
Label2 = .SeriesCollection(2).Points(j).DataLabel.Text
Debug.Print Label1 & " : " & Label2
If Label1 > Label2 Then
 ... Else
 ...
    End If
Next j
End With`

Comment: Okay, Currency formatting doesn't work with Val() so used CDbl().